# Can't log into Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

My Windows 7 (64bit) computer was part of AD, but then I needed to removed it from old domain and join to new domain. I have admin access, so I removed my PC from old domain, renamed it and restarted.

My PC has local admin that I created and the built-in admin account was renamed and disabled. So, after the restart, I tried to login with my local admin account, but was not able. I am sure that my password is correct. I get this message:

"You cannot log on because the logon method you are using is not allowed on this computer."

I really don't understand why Windows 7 won't let me log in as local admin. Now I am stuck in between. My PC was removed from old domain, so I can't use domain accounts to login, and at the same time local account is not working properly.

Would anyone suggest any ideas on how to fix it or why this is the case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did the domain that you left have any policies set to prevent local users from logging in ?

Comment: I think so. I just don't get why when I am off that domain its policies still affect this computer.

Comment: There will be a local group policy to prevent local login. There's a video called "Using chntpw to Bypass Group Policy" at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRjKMCzmXKQ that will show the sort of thing you need to do to bypass it. (I think, not tried it myself - yet)

Answer (score 2):

Connect remotely to the file system (c$) and try to delete the policies from the file system at %SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicy.

Comment: This is unfortunately the "most correct" answer here. If you ever have a moment it could use a bit of explaining as to why he should move the policy files from the location you mentioned to somewhere else.